# How to place cls inside tagfield editor

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, tags

I am using tagfield and want to apply crooss Icon inside the field, which I can use for removal or some event. 
My tagfield code is

```
{
    xtype: 'tagfield',
    growMax  : 10,
    valueField: 'title',
    displayField: 'title',
    parentGrid : me,
    dataIndex:header.getAttribute("DATAINDEX"),
    queryMode: 'local',
    multiSelect: true,
    isFilterDataLoaded: false,
    //cls : 'button-Cross',
    disabled: true,
    listeners:{}
}
```

I am using this css class to apply cross(X) icon, but it is not coming. Also I am mot sure how on click of that event will fier. I was trying `actionCls` but did'nt get much there

```
.button-Cross {
    line-height: 12px;
    width: 18px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: tahoma;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Can any body suggest me what I need to do. and what I am doing wrong. My required image is like this. In black box I want (X). [image]

Note: my `tagfield` is widget column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`triggers`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-triggers) for adding an additional trigger, like:

```
{
   xtype: 'tagfield',
   growMax: 10,
   valueField: 'title',
   displayField: 'title',
   queryMode: 'local',
   multiSelect: true,
   isFilterDataLoaded: false,
   disabled: true,
   triggers: {
       clear: {
           weight: -2,
           cls: 'button-cross',
           handler: function(){}
       },
       picker: {
           handler: 'onTriggerClick',
           scope: 'this'
       }
   }
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1on7

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like charm

Comment: Only `'button-cross'` is may be wrong css. but that I can change. I only needed to know how to insert. :)

Comment: Instead of cross icon I am getting drop down Icon. I checked with fiddle but result is same. ANy reason why this happening.

Comment: @David can you add a link to your fiddle?

Comment: @David have a look at the `index.html`, I've added some style: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1onb

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to do it with image. I am trying like  `background-image : 'resources/images/remove.png';` but not getting.